# SQL multiple group by query, for one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new-ish to sql (and in infrequent user) I have a relatively complex (at least from my point of view) query that I'm having no luck writing.

My relationships are as follow.

People have one Job. People also have one FavoriteHobby.

I would like to query for all people (this part is easy). I would like to group the people by what Job they have. Within the grouping for a giving Job, I would like to "sub group" those people by what their FavoriteHobby is.

Does anyone know how I might put this query together? I'm really struggling!

Given a sample of these people with the following names, jobs, and hobbies

```
   names      obs        hobbies
Alice,      Engineer,    Baseball
Amanda,     Engineer,    Baseball
Adrian,     Engineer,    Hockey
Bill,       Engineer,    Hockey
Bob,        Teacher,     Tennis
Mike,       Teacher,     Tennis
Sansa,      Teacher,     Golf
Jeff,       Teacher,     Golf
```

I would want a result something like this

```
Group A:
    subgroup i: alice, amanda
    subgroup ii: adrian, bill
Group B:
    subgroup i: bob, mike
    subgroup ii: sansa, jeff
```

I appreciate any help a lot. Cheers.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and the results you want.

Comment: Also, consider adding more info like your tables structure. And a perfect question would have a sqlfiddle demo with sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated with some "sample data". I know this is not a standard format or anything... but should illustrate what I'm hoping for. I'm not sure how to do better formatting of this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL queries return result sets that look like tables -- all rows have the same columns.  You could group things by jobs and hobbies:

```
select job, hobby, group_concat(name) as names
from table1
group by job, hobby
order by job, hobby;
```

You can enumerate these using variables:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as grp, job, hobby, group_concat(name) as names
from table1 cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars
group by job, hobby
order by job, hobby;
```

Is this sufficient?  It will give the groups numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4, instead of renumbering within each job.